# How to get the value of next element in java selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have total 3 pages and all three pages contains the email ids and I want that email id using java selenium. But all three pages contains different format of email field and I want that in one single code because I am using the for loop to get that email ids.

Page 1:

```
<p>Test1</p>
<p>abc@abc.com</p>
```

Page 2:

```
<p>
   <br>Contact:<br>  
   Test2
</p>
<p>
   <br>Email:<br>  
   xyz@xyz.com
</p>
```

Page 3:

```
<p>
   <br>Contact:<br>  
   Test3
</p>
<p>
   <br>Email:<br>  
   pqr@pqr.com
</p>
```

So how will I get this email ids in one single code.

I tried

```
email = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Email:')]")).getText();
```

but I got the "email" in that variable but didn't get its value.

Comment: rather than sharing text, share html code and your java code you are trying.

Comment: @GaurangShah I edited my question. Check it once.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Gaurang also meant the Java code you are trying as well.  We are not here to write code for you, but to help you write your own.

Comment: if html is different for each it's never a good idea to use one function to interact with the element. think of the problem you will have when something will change. Also you code will be unnecessary complex.

Comment: Basically there are multiple pages so I will go to that pages and get the emails and contact of it. So I have to be one code for all.
Is there any possibilities to get the content of "Email" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get whole content of P tag which contains email

```
WebElement emailElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[contains(.,'@')]"));
String email = emailElement.getText().toString();
```

After getting text as string you can split or use a stringbuilder to construct actual email.

hope this helps

Comment: This is exactly what I was just about to post.  One edit though, "email.getText()" needs to be "emailElement.getText()".  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
email = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Email:')]/..")).getText();
```